# How do I get distinct records based on a field value with eloquent relation in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I have two models called 'Property' with fields id, property, and other necessary fields and 'ProductProperty' with id, property_id, value, and other necessary fields. I need distinct records for 'value' field from 'ProductProperty' model when making relation with 'Property' model.

Currently, I am getting repetitive records for 'value' field from ProductProperty model when making eager loading with 'Property' model.

[image: Console Screenshot]

Here, I am getting value Germany and Italy several times from ProductProperty model. But I need Germany and Italy one time only.

My controller function code for the above output is as follows.

```
$filterItems = Property::where('is_for_filter', 1)
            ->with(['productProperties'])
            ->get();
```

Please help me getting distinct records from ProperProperty model.

Comment: See this: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/eloquent/getting-distinct-rows-from-a-model-with-relationships

Comment: Ahmad, Can you please give me some clue so that I can write function query in eager loading relation (productProperties)? Suppose, Property::where('is_for_filter', 1)
            ->with(['productProperties' => function($query) {}])
            ->get();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a new relation in your `Property` model for unique related values as

```
public function distinctValues()
{
    return $this->hasMany(\App\Models\ProductProperty::class, 'property_id')
                ->select(['property_id','value'])
                ->distinct();
}
```

And in query just eager load your new relation as

```
$filterItems = Property::with('distinctValues')->where('is_for_filter', 1)->get();
```

Comment: It helps me a lot. Your answer is appreciable. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Asraf If its works can you please check this answer as correct answer see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)